# How can I use '<' inside a <code></code> in html?

Tags: html

I wish to write `<1H Ocean` inside a  `<code> </code>` block which is inside a `<p> </p>` block like

`<p> blah blah blah ... <code><1H Ocean</code> ... </code>`

in a markdown cell in a Jupyter notebook.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `&lt;`.

Check here for a list of HTML entities: https://dev.w3.org/html5/html-author/charref

Comment: I knew about &lt but it did not work because I missed the ';'. Thanks.